# Genshin Impact full screen problem in tablet mode on Laptop

Tags: genshin-impact

I play in tablet mode on my laptop,  so the weakest flip I do while opening the game has to look like

[image]

I used to reinstall the game and it works, but that takes too much time.

Comment: "The weakest flip i do while opening genshin genshin has to look like"? Sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: @Joachim seems something about portrait / landscape rotation? It is difficult to understand right now.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go into the Paimon menu
2. Click settings (should be a bottom icon on the left sidebar)
3. Go to graphics
4. Depending on what you want either set the screen size to that OR, if it's already on the size you want, just switch it to a smaller one and then back to the one you want (this is what I have to do, it kinda resets it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's taking the mobile game build or the PC game build.

Do you have a launcher? (A screen that opens up before the game to do updates and has a big Launch yellow button)

If it's the PC game build I would look for, in the settings, the screen settings (resolution) and make sure it's something like 1920x1080. My guess is that as soon as the tablet flips in portrait mode, it forces a resolution for portrait (that will show the most of the game possible in a supported resolution) but when it goes back to landscape it doesn't do that check.

Comment: The bottom left corner which shows the build, shows it's Windows.

Comment: But still that can still be a windows tablet, that does some weird stuff if you flip from landscape to portrait.